# Edit link on tags pulls the contents down

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tags, design

I noticed this problem on Stack Overflow Portuguese (currently on private beta). The edit link pulls the content down as it doesn't fit on the same line or if there isn't that bottom line about week/month status.

[image: edit doesn't fit]

However, this is not a problem only on SOpt, I noticed the same happens on [Stack Overflow (tags page)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=1034&tab=popular).

[image: edit doesn't fit so]

And if it happens here as well, it means this problem could be all over Stack Exchange...

Comment: @Oded the bug appears to be the edit link appearing for tags with no questions. It happens only with some of the tags, probably where all questions were deleted and the daily tag buster job didn't yet clean up.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I propose it to move the edit link up.

[image: edit link up]

If this could be a problem, my next suggestion is to remove this link and leave it only on the tag hover menu.